# ImageView fills parent's width OR height, but maintains aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a square image (though this problem also applies to rectangular images).  I want to display the image as large as possible, stretching them if necessary, to fill their parents, while still maintaining the aspect ratio. The image is smaller than the ImageView. The problem is, I can't stretch the image and "match" the height and width of the ImageView.

This is my XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:scaleType="fitCenter"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
              android:layout_below="@id/image"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="18dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name2"
              android:layout_below="@id/name"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="14dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have used many combinations of `fill_parent`, `wrap_content` with multiple scaleTypes: `fitCenter`, `fitStart`, `fitEnd`, `centerInside`, and they all draw the images in the right aspect ratio, but **none of them actually scale the images up and the ImageView itself**, resulting in either the TextViews get pushed all the way down off the screen, blank spaces inside the ImageView, image not scaled, or image cropped.

I can't quite figure the right combination for this.

Comment: try the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355130/android-imageview-size-not-scaling-with-source-image

Comment: @Tim: I already set `adjustViewBounds=true`. It somehow did not resize the ImageView bounds.

Comment: Do you have only one image or multiple? Have you thought of using a `ScrollView`? Is your image height bigger than the screen height? If so, how do you want your layout to look? Your `TextView` `name`, is it supposed to be to the left or below of the image? If you want all 3 views to fit your screen, they should all have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Comment: @slybloty I have multiple, but I'm displaying one image. I should have worded this question better. It is displaying one image.

Comment: Have you tried `android:scaleType="fitXY"`? It stretches the image to match the width and height you assign (i.e, it doesn't respect aspect ratio).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageView adjustViewBounds not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719617/imageview-adjustviewbounds-not-working)

Comment: you can try this response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554682/android-imageview-adjusting-parents-height-and-fitting-width/12283909#12283909

Answer (score 115):

These:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

should resize the image and change the size of the bounds to fit the new image size. If it does not do that on your device post the image you are using and what device you are testing on.

Comment: Does not work. I cannot post the images because they are proprietary, but they are just standard 128x128 PNGs. This also occuring on the emulator. So it's not device specific issues. These images are smaller than the ImageView. I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: adjustViewBounds is not enough, it "will not increase the size of the ImageView beyond the natural dimensions of the drawable": http://stackoverflow.com/a/7732684/804479

Comment: I think the solution is to use scaleType="centerCrop", if you can accept the image to be cropped...

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Foam Guy will this work if i m getting images from server ?

Comment: @Erum shouldn't matter where the image came from.

Comment: first time when I used this solution in recyclerview images it is working.Then I have uploaded new image and checked all images in recyclerview it is now working.Anyone know why it is happening?

Comment: I know we aren't supposed to add these kind of comments but... You rock!

Answer (score 49):

Use this code :
`android:scaleType="fitXY"`

For more details about image scaling, look what's motioned in this article [here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.in/2014/01/imageview-scaletypes.html)

Summary:

- `center`

> Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling

[image]

- `centerCrop`

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view

[image]

- `centerInside`

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding)

[image]

- `fitCenter`

[image]

- `fitEnd`

[image]

- `fitStart`

[image]

- `fitXY`

[image]

- `matrix`

> Scale using the image matrix when drawing

[image]

more details [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=1096591845-Android_Weekly_221&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-1096591845-337990929) new article

Comment: Why this answer doesn't have any vote? Only this one works for me!

Comment: Because it doesn't maintain the aspect ratio of the source image. See [here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.in/2014/01/imageview-scaletypes.html).

Comment: Showing all cases with each image was very helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: If ImageView.background=#000000 you see that ImageView occupy the space of parent layout;

Comment: best answer now I can understand all of them

Answer (score 22):

This xml code will work!. If you are specifying that your apps width is always same as the window, then the `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` will set the height respective to the ration of the image.

```
        <ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/screen"/>
```

Comment: May the stackoverflow god bless your soul. I spent a whole day on this, gave up with either a narrow image or one with white sides. Came back this morning and figured "Hey let me google it"  @garbagecollector should really accept this answer!!

Comment: @ИвоНедев stackoverflow god is not blessing me somehow, it's not working. image aspect ratio is not keep.

Answer (score 13):

Use this code with view layout parameters as wrapcontent

android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Hope this it will work.

Comment: adjustViewBounds is not enough, it "will not increase the size of the ImageView beyond the natural dimensions of the drawable": http://stackoverflow.com/a/7732684/804479

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, android:adjustViewBounds not doing its job and having a padding at the top of the image. Into a relative layout that had match_parent values for the width and the height, I had:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/transparent">

   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" ...
```

I changed the Relative layout to a Linear layout with wrap_content values for width and height and now it is ok:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: After many hours of searching I also changed RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. But in my case an ImageView hadn't been shown.

Comment: My ImageView:
"<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IV_InformationPic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>"

Was inside a Relative layout, the ImageView would deal with it's height correctly but it had extra padding on the left and the right somewhy.

After reading this answer and @CoolMind's comment, I tried and changed it into a LinearLayout and poof, the ImageView has no more side padding.
I would love to understand this voodoo.

Comment: @MatanKoby, happy coding! Android has many secrets and dungeons.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to adjust it programmaticaly? I think it works really well if you calculate the height of your `TextView`s and adjust the height and width of the image based on this.

```
private void adjustImageView()
{
    //Get the display dimensions
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    //TextView name
    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText("your name text goes here");
    name.measure(0, 0);

    //name TextView height
    int nameH = name.getMeasuredHeight();

    //TextView name2
    TextView name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name2);
    name2.setText("your name2 text goes here");
    name2.measure(0, 0);

    //name2 TextView height
    int name2H = name2.getMeasuredHeight();

    //Original image
    Bitmap imageOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

    //Width/Height ratio of your image
    float imageOriginalWidthHeightRatio = (float) imageOriginal.getWidth() / (float) imageOriginal.getHeight();

    //Calculate the new width and height of the image to display 
    int imageToShowHeight = metrics.heightPixels - nameH - name2H;
    int imageToShowWidth = (int) (imageOriginalWidthHeightRatio * imageToShowHeight);

    //Adjust the image width and height if bigger than screen
    if(imageToShowWidth > metrics.widthPixels)
    {
        imageToShowWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        imageToShowHeight = (int) (imageToShowWidth / imageOriginalWidthHeightRatio);
    }

    //Create the new image to be shown using the new dimensions 
    Bitmap imageToShow = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageOriginal, imageToShowWidth, imageToShowHeight, true);

    //Show the image in the ImageView
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageBitmap(imageToShow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in imageview.
To create an image with width equals screen width, and height proportionally set according to aspect ratio, do the following.  Here I mention how to load image to imageview from url.

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                        // creating the image that maintain aspect ratio with width of image is set to screenwidth.
                        int width = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
                        int diw = resource.getWidth();
                        if (diw > 0) {
                            int height = 0;
                            height = width * resource.getHeight() / diw;
                            resource = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, width, height, false);
                        }
                                              imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps.