# How to make gone the overflowing in Android xml

Tags: android

I'm searching an overflow attribute in Android but I've not find. I have an xml file;

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/add_place_map_popup"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placeProfileAddressIconBig"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/place_rec_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I wanna make this image view more big. But when I make more big, the RelativeLayout become big, too. When I have an overflow in the RelativeLayout because of imageView, I wanna make the outflows "visible:invisible" or "visible:gone".

Can anyone tell me, how can I hide overflowing in Layout?

Comment: check this answer for understanding how images scaling works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826422/imageview-fills-parents-width-or-height-but-maintains-aspect-ratio/20477655#20477655

Answer (score 0):

```
Use `android:clipChildren="false"` in parent:
```

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placeProfileAddressIconBig"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/place_rec_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```