# Issue extra space - two imageViews for as list items

Tags: android, imageview, space, listitem

I have an issue making two ImageViews beside eachother without any space between them.

Here's the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="1111"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEval1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/green_square"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEval2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/orange_square"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout gives the design as in the screenshot :

[Layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLHfA.png)

What i want to achieve, is that those two squares (Green and orange) to be beside eachother.

**This is what i want to achive :**

[To achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM6YM.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try taking out the `layout_weight` on the `ImageViews`.

Comment: I tried your answer, but the design is the same. i did uploaded , as an edit, an screenshot of the design i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

and for more information, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826422/imageview-fills-parents-width-or-height-but-maintains-aspect-ratio/20477655#20477655)

Answer (score 0):

Setting **layout_weight** to  Imageview does that exactly in your situation. Try to remove weights.

Change layout to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="1111"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEval1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/green_square"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
       />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEval2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/orange_square"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this, but the design is the same. i did uploaded , as an edit, an screenshot of the design i want to achieve.

Comment: thats exactly what i tried and worked. i posted the answer minutes ago. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MysteryDev sorry, There was no notification about answer, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the **layout_weight** and added ***android:adjustViewBounds="true"***, and the design became what i wanted to to achieve.