# image not resizing in View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an android app that loads a picture from a live webcam feed. This image is displayed within the app. The image would fill the screen nicely but for some reason - because of some Android update (App is about 4 years old and problem is old also..) the image does not resize and remains as a small box.

This is the XML code I use for the image:

```
     <com.test.LoaderImageView
              android:id="@+id/loaderImageView"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         image="http://www.tests.com/webcam.jpg"           />
```

Comment: I can post a screenshot to aid in the problem solving

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the scaleType to `fitXY` & width/height to `fill_parent`:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

This may mess up the aspect ratio. If that's a problem, but image-clipping is fine – try `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

You're using a custom ImageView class, so make sure `image='..'` is `android:src='...'` – and not `android:background='...'`

SRC: [ImageView fills parent's width OR height, but maintains aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826422/imageview-fills-parents-width-or-height-but-maintains-aspect-ratio)
&
[How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```