# Change the size of ImageView on zooming

Tags: android, imageview, pinchzoom, zooming

I am using chrisbanes PhotoView to implement pinch zoom..Image zooms on pinching and double tapping but i can't see that my image streched to full screen on zooming..on zooming it looks that image zooms inside a box and part of image disappears on zooming...How can i implement image zoom so that height of Image increases on zooming?I am using NetworkImageView ( of Volley library).

```
NetworkImageView imageView;
 PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

                imageView = (NetworkImageView) mImgPagerView.findViewById(R.id.imageitem);

                mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
```

NetworkImageView.java ( of Volley library)

```
     import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        import android.util.AttributeSet;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageContainer;

public class NetwrokImageView extends ImageView {
    /** The URL of the network image to load */
    private String mUrl;
    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used as a placeholder until the network image is loaded.
     */
    private int mDefaultImageId;
    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used if the network response fails.
     */
    private int mErrorImageId;
    /** Local copy of the ImageLoader. */
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    public NetworkImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }
    public NetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
    public NetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    /**
     * Sets URL of the image that should be loaded into this view. Note that calling this will
     * immediately either set the cached image (if available) or the default image specified by
     * {@link NetworkImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} on the view.
     *
     * NOTE: If applicable, {@link NetworkImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} and
     * {@link NetworkImageView#setErrorImageResId(int)} should be called prior to calling
     * this function.
     *
     * @param url The URL that should be loaded into this ImageView.
     * @param imageLoader ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
     */
    public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        mUrl = url;
        mImageLoader = imageLoader;
// The URL has potentially changed. See if we need to load it.
        loadImageIfNecessary();
    }
    /**
     * Sets the default image resource ID to be used for this view until the attempt to load it
     * completes.
     */
    public void setDefaultImageResId(int defaultImage) {
        mDefaultImageId = defaultImage;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the error image resource ID to be used for this view in the event that the image
     * requested fails to load.
     */
    public void setErrorImageResId(int errorImage) {
        mErrorImageId = errorImage;
    }
    /**
     * Loads the image for the view if it isn't already loaded.
     */
    private void loadImageIfNecessary() {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
// if the view's bounds aren't known yet, hold off on loading the image.
        if (width == 0 && height == 0) {
            return;
        }
// if the URL to be loaded in this view is empty, cancel any old requests and clear the
// currently loaded image.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUrl)) {
            ImageContainer oldContainer = (ImageContainer) getTag();
            if (oldContainer != null) {
                oldContainer.cancelRequest();
                setImageBitmap(null);
            }
            return;
        }
        ImageContainer oldContainer = (ImageContainer) getTag();
// if there was an old request in this view, check if it needs to be canceled.
        if (oldContainer != null && oldContainer.getRequestUrl() != null) {
            if (oldContainer.getRequestUrl().equals(mUrl)) {
// if the request is from the same URL, return.
                return;
            } else {
// if there is a pre-existing request, cancel it if it's fetching a different URL.
                oldContainer.cancelRequest();
                setImageBitmap(null);
            }
        }
// The pre-existing content of this view didn't match the current URL. Load the new image
// from the network.
        ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(this, mDefaultImageId, mErrorImageId));
// update the tag to be the new bitmap container.
        setTag(newContainer);
// look at the contents of the new container. if there is a bitmap, load it.
        final Bitmap bitmap = newContainer.getBitmap();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        loadImageIfNecessary();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        ImageContainer oldContainer = (ImageContainer) getTag();
        if (oldContainer != null) {
// If the view was bound to an image request, cancel it and clear
// out the image from the view.
            oldContainer.cancelRequest();
            setImageBitmap(null);
// also clear out the tag so we can reload the image if necessary.
            setTag(null);
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:+'
```

xml

```
<com.xyz.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageitem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/image_loading" />
```

ImageView is inside FrameLayout

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        >
```

Image before zooming
[image]
Image after zooming
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your issue. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10632396/2649012) helps?

Comment: @DerGolem Besides this code i even tried using ChrisBanes https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView but the same issue exist..Image zooms on pinching and double tapping but size of imageview remains fixed..it doesn't increase on zooming..i want just like in whatsapp size of imageview increases on zooming..maybe some issue is in my layout file thats why i posted my complete xml layout file..plzz check it out..

Comment: I don't use WhatsApp (I use Telegram), so I can't figure this "ImageView" zooming, instead of the "Image zooming". Is it your meaning? the ImageView has to change size accordingly to its contents?

Comment: yeah..imageview has to change size according to content..so when i zoom image,image view should increase in size..but here my imageview remains of fixed size on zooming-in and zooming-out but the image does zoom on zooming

Comment: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5355281/2649012. If I understood correctly, what it does is to fit the ImageView to its contents. Defaults to false.

Comment: @DerGolem I tried adding  android:adjustViewBounds="true" but same issue..imagview height remains fixed..only the content inside imagview zoom-in and zoom-out

Comment: Oh! now that I think about... I missed something obvious: where you zoom the image size, you could re-set the ImageView size, too.

Comment: thnku for ur time..wht code should i put for resizing the imageview on zooming..check out my above code ..am i not scaling the view on zooming?

Comment: @DerGolem I doubt some issue is in my layout xml file but i am not getting..

Comment: Well, if the layout_height and width are set to wrap_content, it should automatically change its size to fit its contents without the need to set it programmatically.

Comment: i have set the height to wrap_content only but still its not adjusting..width is fine..width changes for small images on zooming..

Comment: width is fine..width increases for small images on zooming.

Comment: So probably height has to be set same as width?

Comment: if i set height match_parent then image comes on whole screen and looks stretched..also part of image seems missing..

Comment: My last idea (then I finished them) is to play with the ImageView's scaleType attribute, as shown here: http://etcodehome.blogspot.it/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html

Comment: ok..thnku for ur time..i'll try that and let u know if it works..

Comment: do this   `<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/meme_image_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_centerInParent="false">` and `<com.xyz.AspectRatioImageView2
            android:id="@+id/imageitem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="matrix" //-- no need
            android:layout_gravity="center" //--> no need

            android:background="@drawable/image_loading" />`

Comment: if still having problem, just put in in s separate layout and then try. ok

Comment: ok..i'll try nd let u know

Comment: @AZ_ I tried using separate layouts..putting content of FrameLayout in one xml file and rest in other xml file but same result..size of imageView remains fixed while zoom-in and zoom-out..I am using ViewPager and content of FrameLayout is part of ViewPager

Comment: @AZ_ u can check out updated layout file in question..

Comment: @AZ_ I think the issue is  because image container doesn't resize when the image zooms..check out my complete java code above

Comment: @DerGolem I think the issue is  because image container doesn't resize when the image zooms..check out my complete java code above

Comment: @DerGolem ImageContainer doesn't have setWidth() and setHeight() methods..i am setting width and height through  ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
                new ImageListener(){}..

Comment: I see. I thought it had the same counterparts of `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`

Comment: Maybe in  ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl, new ImageListener(){} where i am assigning containerWidth and containerHeight,I might be going wrong?

Comment: When I drag image it looks like tht image is in rectangle container and part of image disappears when i drag it outside tht container.

Comment: Check out..i have attached screenshots in question..

Comment: I am using ImageContainer defined in ImageLoader class of Volley

Comment: I tried this..My ImageView is exending this..https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java ..and I used  https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView still i can't see that my image streched to full screen on zooming..on zooming it looks that image zooms inside a box and part of image disappears  on zooming

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Google's example?](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) It looks like you might be able to animate to a hidden fullscreen container similar to what they are doing, and continue zooming from there.

Comment: same problem to me

Comment: Did you got the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Better try a different approach if youre stuck

You can find below a link to a class created by Jason Polites that will allow you to handle pinch zooms on custom ImageViews: https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview.

Just include this package into your application and then you will be able to use a custom `GestureImaveView` in your XML files:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:gesture-image="http://schemas.polites.com/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.polites.android.GestureImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    gesture-image:min-scale="0.1"
    gesture-image:max-scale="10.0"
    gesture-image:strict="false"/>
```

This class handles pinch zooms, but also double taps.

Answer credit goes to [Yoann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206688/yoann-hercouet) :)

Comment: I think the issue is  because image container doesn't resize when the image zooms..check out my complete java code above

Comment: I tried this..My ImageView is exending this..https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java ..and I used  https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView still i can't see that my image streched to full screen on zooming..on zooming it looks that image zooms inside a box and part of image disappears on zooming

Answer (score 1):

I will highly recommend having a look at Photo View:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

It was developed by Chris Banes who is one of the actual developers that worked on the Android development team, so you can't go wrong here. This library will save you A LOT of headaches.

Usage is as simple as:

```
ImageView mImageView;
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  // Any implementation of ImageView can be used!
  mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

  // Set the Drawable displayed
  Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);
  mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

  // Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming functionality.
  mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
}
```

Comment: In my project it is required to add function to single tap also..If I am using chrisbanes PhotoView can i add function to singletap also on ImageView as it is required to show and hide panel on single tap?

Comment: My ImageView is exending this..https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java ..and I used  chrisbanes PhotoView still i can't see that my image streched to full screen on zooming..on zooming it looks that image zooms inside a box and part of image disappears  on zooming

Answer (score 1):

I created a fully functional project on github. link in the end of the answer.

**Problem elements:**

*1. Getting touch events and use it's variables to set image zoom level and window. (left, top, right, bottom).*

**Sample Code:** only part of image will be showing at a time. therefore setting `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` will achieve the zooming.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageFrameLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Touch Listener (you can modify this to add your click event)

```
OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        float distx, disty;
        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){   
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains the initial starting location.
                touchState = TOUCH;
                currentX = (int) event.getRawX();
                currentY = (int) event.getRawY();
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                //A non-primary pointer has gone down.
                touchState = PINCH;
                //Get the distance when the second pointer touch
                distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);

                dist0 = (float) Math.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);
                distLast = dist0;
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //A change has happened during a press gesture (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).
                if(touchState == PINCH){
                    // pinch started calculate scale step.
                    //Get the current distance
                    distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                    disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                    distCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);
                    if (Math.abs(distCurrent-distLast) >= 35) // check sensitivity
                    {
                        stepScale = distCurrent/dist0;
                        distLast = distCurrent;
                        drawMatrix(); // draw new image
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // move started.
                    if (currentX==-1 && currentY==-1) 
                    {
                        // first move after touch down
                        currentX = (int) event.getRawX();
                        currentY = (int) event.getRawY();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // calculate move window variable.
                        int x2 = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y2 = (int) event.getRawY();
                        int dx = (currentX - x2);
                        int dy = (currentY - y2);
                        left += dx;
                        top += dy;
                        currentX = x2;
                        currentY = y2;
                        drawMatrix(); // draw new image window
                    }
                }
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //A pressed gesture has finished.

                touchState = IDLE;
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                //A non-primary pointer has gone up.
                if (touchState == PINCH)
                {
                    // pinch ended. reset variable.
                }
                touchState = TOUCH;
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

*2. Since zooming required. I assume that we are using high quality images.*

Therefore, loading the full sized quality image when zoomed out won't benefit, since the user won't recognise the small details. But it will increase memory usage and could crash for very large images.

> Solution Trick: On zooming out load larger window with lower quality.
>   On zoom in load smaller window with higher quality.

The proposed solution checks the current zoom level and image window required and based on that gets only part of the image with specific quality using **BitmapRegionDecoder** and **BitmapFactory**.

**Sample Code:**

Initialise image decoder that is going to be used later to ask for a part of the image:

```
    InputStream is = null;
    bitmapRegionDecoder = null;

    try {
        is = getAssets().open(res_id); // get image stream from assets. only the stream, no mem usage
        bitmapRegionDecoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(is, false);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true; // only specs needed. no image yet!
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bounds); // get image specs.

    try {
        is.close(); // close stream no longer needed.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Ask for image with quality and window:

```
    Rect pRect = new Rect(left, top, left + newWidth, top + newHeight);
    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (tempScale <= 2.75) // you can map scale with quality better than this.
        inSampleSize = 2;

    bounds.inSampleSize = inSampleSize; // set image quality. takes binary steps only. 1, 2, 4, 8 . .
    bm = bitmapRegionDecoder.decodeRegion(pRect, bounds);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

[project on github](https://github.com/hasanalbukhari/Android-Image-Zooming).

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this issue in photo view image zoom library. i was changed the layout_height is "wrap_content" to "match_parent. It's working fine for me.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

```
<com.xyz.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageitem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_loading" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change the ImageView's size, you need to change its layoutParams, as I've demonstrated [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519921/how-to-animate-imageview-from-center-crop-to-fill-the-screen-and-vice-versa-fac). You can also change its scale as of Honeycomb.

However, if you wish to just move a rectangle within the image, which also zooms nicely (like other apps that allow to crop), you can use a library like ["**cropper**](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper)" or if you don't need the features there you can use a library like [**TouchImageView**](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

Comment: I think the issue is tht image container doesn't resize when the image zooms

Comment: When I drag image it looks like tht image is in rectangle container and part of image disappears when i drag it outside tht container..

Comment: plzz check out my above code..i think that issue is ImageContainer mImageContainer doesn't resize when i zoom the image..

Comment: Code is too long. Can you please post a sample (and with as short code as possible) project that I can just import and run? Maybe also post a video showing what's wrong?

Comment: Please just upload to a file uploading website, the whole project, but minimized so that I could focus on the problem and find it easily.

Comment: I tried this..My ImageView is exending this..https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java ..and I used  https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView still i can't see that my image streched to full screen on zooming..on zooming it looks that image zooms inside a box and part of image disappears on zooming

Comment: Can you please make a new, minimized project that has the problem and upload it, so that I could look at it instead of guessing according to the libraries you used? It's really hard to pinpoint the problem this way.

Comment: Thanku for ur time..I have posted the code above which u can just import and run..also i have attached the screenshots..plzz check it out

Answer (score 0):

It is because the ImageView has a view height of "wrap_content". Change it to "match_parent" and set the scaleType of the image to be "centerInside" to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when using NetworkImageView does not behave the same as an ImageView, I solve it by creating an xml design for portrait and landscape

**PORTRAIT**

**layout/item_image.xml**

height="match_parent" and width="wrap_content", important **scaleType="fitCenter"**

```
 <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/imageitem"/>
```

**LAND**

**layout/land/item_image.xml**

now in the land layout the height="wrap_content" and width="match_parent", always **scaleType="fitCenter"**

```
 <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/imageitem"/>
```

It's also important to instantiate the PhotoViewAttacher object after assigning the resource to the NetworkImageView control

```
    NetworkImageView imageView;
    PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

        imageView = (NetworkImageView) 
        mImgPagerView.findViewById(R.id.imageitem);
        //firts set the image resources, i'm using Android Volley Request
        ImageLoader imageLoader = MySocialMediaSingleton.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageView.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
        //next create instance of PhotoViewAttecher
        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
        mAttacher.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use imageviewtouch and have same problem. To solve it you can wrap imageview inside layout without any other children. Example :

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toplayout">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/imageitem"/>
</LinearLayout>
```